# How can I attach dates to my timeline?

Tags: jquery, date, timeline

I've created a timeline with marker increments to show time in between two dates, and it works fine but I want to now attach the date to it's appropriate increment marker.

See me Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vK8WA/

As you can see, we get the dates, figure out how many markers to display and how much spacing to give them to make them equally placed on the timeline, and create the elements.

If the amount of days in between two dates is equal to or less than `31` we display markers for each day, but if the amount of days is equal to or greater than `32`, we display markers in weeks (7 days).

How can I attach the *date* of each increment to it's respective marker `<div>`? Help?

**Edit**

As suggested below, I used `i` in my method to increment date numbers on the timeline. See my new Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vK8WA/1/

My problem *now* is the numbers just keep getting higher. I need to extract the month name, as well as roll over the number back to 1 once the date gets to 31 (or 30, 28, depending on the month) as well as get the next month in order. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: where are the markers? can you simplify the code, paste it here and stick to some straightforward question?

Comment: why you can't attach the date during the function "// Insert each marker" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vK8WA/2/), and I think you'll be happy with the results.

- Created variables for `startDate` and `endDate`
- Produced the markers based on a `markerDate` variable that gets incremented by either 1 or 7 days, based on your existing logic.
- Added a list of month abbreviations and an `ordinal` function to assist in producing formatted output
- Added `text-align: center;` to your css for `time-increment`

The result now looks like this:

[image: Timeline Image]

Answer (score 0):

Well excuse me if I miss understood you're question, one way to attach the proper date would be to, get the starting date which you already have and increment it by i which you use in you're loop. Then just can just print out the given result which was computed.

Comment: I did what you said, but now i have a new set of problems. See my update. Think you could help?